# Laravel Iamge Validation jpeg failed

Tags: laravel, image, validation

I have FormRequest with rule

```
 'photo' =>  'required|image',
```

If i upload jpeg image, this rule failed, because in src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php in method validateImage sets extensions for check

```
return $this->validateMimes($attribute, $value, ['jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'webp']);
```

but for image/jpeg in validateMimes laravel set extensions as 'jpg'

It's because in /symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php method guessExtension return first extension by mimes, and mimes for
image/jpeg is

```
'image/jpeg' => ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe'],
```

in /symfony/mime/MimeTypes.php

How to fix this error?

Comment: what's your version?

Comment: Exactly. Confused the project thought the latest version and in this project 5.8 It will be necessary to update.

Answer (score 1):

What content type has your request ? Try to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.